# Computer won't autoconnect to hidden WiFi on startup. I have to turn off/on wif adapter, then manually select. VPN tunnel sharing

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, vpn, nordvpn

Upon power-up and log on, there's a message similar to

> unable to connect to network.

I have to turn off/on the WiFi adapter in settings, and then manually select the hidden network. Autoconnect is enabled.

On a Windows 10 laptop I am sharing a NordLynx Tunnel (NordVPN), which is an adapter listed in Network Connections. (Right click, properties, sharing, Allow other computers.., Home network connection: Ethernet adapter.)

The Ethernet adapter is a multiport USB adapter (no native Ethernet port), with an Ethernet cable running to a LinkSys router.

Sometimes I also have to unshare/share the adapter on the Windows PC. The ? appears over the WiFi symbol until I do this. These seems to be required about 1/3 of the time.